# ObservableCollection Count Property not updated after items are added

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have 2 classes, one a `ViewModels` that stores an `ObservableCollection<T> dataSource` and a method `LoadMore()` which adds 10 new items per request. The other class is `xaml.cs` to get the data from `dataSource` using `LoadMore()`.

When I try to get new data using the code below it doesn't seem to update the `Count` property of `dataSource`, because it is always 10 items. I already tried using instance object and static class. How could I fix it?

```
ViewModels itemSource = new ViewModels();

itemSource.LoadMore(max_id);
if (itemSource.dataSource.Count == 100) // <=== .Count = 10
{
   //action
    max_id += 10;
}

itemSource.LoadMore(max_id);
if (itemSource.dataSource.Count == 100) // <=== Problem here .Count always 10, never growing up
{
   //action
}
```

Sample of ViewModels class like this

```
public class ViewModels
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> dataSource{ get; private set; }
    public ViewModels()
    {
         dataSource= new ObservableCollection<Model>();
    }

    public void LoadMore(int max_id)
    {
        (Get.Data(max_id)).ForEach(d=> dataSource.Add(d));

    }
}
```

Comment: I'd guess there is a bug in the code adding the items to the collection. So you need to show more code, ideally a small, self contained example which compiles and reproduces the problem.

Comment: I updated the code in question...

Comment: What does `Get.Data(max_id)` do? Have you set a breakpoint and checked that it actually returns the values you expect?

Comment: Works, I already set a breakpoint and check dataSource increase per 10, 20, etc... but the caller still get Count as 10.

Comment: Shouldn't the above code state `ViewModel.dataSource`? Where does `dataSource` come from?

Comment: Ah ok, my copy code not clear.. I update it again, my code works, the point is method LoadMore add new 10 items each called, so in a second call LoadMore on breakpoint dataSource have 20 items. But second itemSource.dataSource.count after execute still 10, not 20

Answer (score -1):

Found it, ObservableCollection.Add() method not complete when itemSource.dataSource.Count executed. Now fix.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this, please explain more, i am also suffering from this problem in a MVVM project.

Comment: this answer is too confusing.